# In class object, how to auto update attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class which has multiple attributes that are related, for example:

```
class SomeClass：
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.list = range(n)
        self.listsquare = [ x**2 for x in self.list ]
```

If I make an object normally that would no problem, with

```
a = SomeClass(10)
```

I will get 2 lists, `a.list` and `a.listsquare`.

Now if I want to make a empty object first, and assign one attribute to it, I want the other attributes to be automatically updated, for example if I do

```
b = SomeClass()
b.list = range(5,10)
```

I want `b.listsquare` to be automatically updated, and also the other way around (assign `b.listsquare` and auto update `b.list`). Is this possible? Is *Class* the right choice for this?

---

Thanks to you all, but I'm completely overwhelmed by all the different answers. Can anyone give a complete solution so I can learn write my own?

I would like to achieve a class `Foo` with 3 attributes `length`, `list` and `listsquare` such that:

1. If I do `a = Foo(3)`, I get `a.length = 3`, `a.list = [0, 1, 2]`, `a.listsquare = [0, 1, 4]`.
2. If I do `b = Foo().list = [5, 6]`, I get `b.length = 2`, `b.listsquare = [25, 36]`.
3. If I do `c = Foo().listsquare = [4, 9]`, I get `c.length = 2`, `c.list = [2, 3]`.

Comment: The code you have given us doesn't work. classes are defined by 'class' not 'def' and are initialized via the 'def __init__(self, ...)' method. You have defined a function with 1 required param called 'self' and 1 optional param called 'n'. When you call SomeClass(10), the function tries to assign 'list' to the 10 object and fails. - oh, looks like the question is being reformatted... so never mind.

Comment: Sorry, I made the corrections. I'm not very familiar with it right now.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

if updating one property due to an update on another property is what you're looking for (instead of recomputing the value of the downstream property on access) use property setters:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list = range(0, n)

    @property
    def list(self):
        return self._list
    @list.setter
    def list(self, val):
        self._list = val
        self._listsquare = [x**2 for x in self._list ]

    @property
    def listsquare(self):
        return self._listsquare
    @listsquare.setter
    def listsquare(self, val):
        self.list = [int(pow(x, 0.5)) for x in val]

>>> c = SomeClass(5)
>>> c.listsquare
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c.list = range(0,6)
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c.listsquare
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> c.listsquare = [x**2 for x in range(0,10)]
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to define 3 properties (`size`, `list`, `listsquare`) so when I update one of them the other 2 will update?

Comment: that is correct. i've updated the above answer to work the way you wanted - the size attribute feel necessary anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely. But use a **property** instead.

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def __init__(self, n=5):
    self.mylist = range(n)

  @property
  def listsquare(self):
    return [ x**2 for x in self.mylist ]

a = SomeClass()
a.mylist = [4, 5, 8]
print a.listsquare
```

Caching of the property value is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great! What about the other way around? Can I define `a.listsquare` and get `a.mylist`?

Comment: Yes. Just add a setter to your property.

Answer (score 5):

Ignacio's @property solution is great but it recalculates the list every time you reference listsquare - that could get expensive. Mathew's solution is great, but now you have function calls. You can combine these with the 'property' function. Here I define a getter and a setter for my_list (I just couldn't call it 'list'!) that generates listsquare:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, n=5):
        self.my_list = range(n)

    def get_my_list(self):
        return self._my_list

    def set_my_list(self, val):
        self._my_list = val
        # generate listsquare when my_list is updated
        self.my_listsquare = [x**2 for x in self._my_list]

    # now my_list can be used as a variable
    my_list = property(get_my_list, set_my_list, None, 'this list is squared')

x = SomeClass(3)
print x.my_list, x.my_listsquare
x.my_list = range(10)
print x.my_list, x.my_listsquare
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: thanks to the folks pointing out i had initialized the list incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just use setter methods, like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, n=5):
        self.set_list(range(n))

    def set_list(self, n):
        self.list = n
        self.listsquare = [ x**2 for x in self.list ]

b = SomeClass()
b.set_list(range(5,10))
```