# attribute that updates based on the value of another attribute in python 3

Tags: python, class, attributes

Say I have a class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attr = ''
        self.a_list = []
        self.empty_check = bool(self.a_list)
myFoo = Foo()
myFoo.a_list.append(1)
```

Much like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916284/in-python-class-object-how-to-auto-update-attributes), I want `empty_check` to change to `True` all by itself, without me having to do anything else, as soon as something is appended to the list.  As it is above, `myFoo.empty_check` is still `False`.  However, I want mine to go "one way".  That is, I don't want `myFoo.empty_check = True` to change `myFoo.a_list` into `[]`.  (So technically not a duplicate, right?)

How can I accomplish this?

It seems I should be using property setters, but despite googling around for a few hours, including reading up on the linked question, I still don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) , the property would be evaluated everytime you try to access it, so you would end up checking the latest `self.a_list` . Also, if you only specify the getter for the property, without setter, you would not be able to do - `myFoo.empty_check = True` , etc. Example -

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attr = ''
        self.a_list = []
    @property
    def empty_check(self):
        return bool(self.a_list)
myFoo = Foo()
print(myFoo.empty_check)
myFoo.a_list.append(1)
print(myFoo.empty_check)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.some_attr = ''
...         self.a_list = []
...     @property
...     def empty_check(self):
...         return bool(self.a_list)
...
>>> myFoo = Foo()
>>> print(myFoo.empty_check)
False
>>> myFoo.a_list.append(1)
>>> print(myFoo.empty_check)
True
>>> myFoo.empty_check = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (I changed some things to follow better practices):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attr = ''
        self.a_list = []

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
        return not self.a_list
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> my_foo = Foo()
>>> print(my_foo.is_empty)
True
>>> my_foo.a_list.append(1)
>>> print(my_foo.is_empty)
False
>>> my_foo.is_empty = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>>
```

A `property` essentially gives you the syntax of accessing an attribute's value, while behind the scenes it's calling a method. Properties aren't just for getting a value; you can also use them for setting and deleting. For more information, see [the `property` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).