# In class object, how to auto update attributes when you change only one entry of a list?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have seen this answer for a very similar question:

[*In class object, how to auto update attributes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916491/5726899)

I will paste the code here:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list = range(0, n)

    @property
    def list(self):
        return self._list
    @list.setter
    def list(self, val):
        self._list = val
        self._listsquare = [x**2 for x in self._list ]

    @property
    def listsquare(self):
        return self._listsquare
    @listsquare.setter
    def listsquare(self, val):
        self.list = [int(pow(x, 0.5)) for x in val]

>>> c = SomeClass(5)
>>> c.listsquare
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c.list = range(0,6)
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c.listsquare
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> c.listsquare = [x**2 for x in range(0,10)]
>>> c.list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In this code, when I update the list using:

```
>>> c.list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

c.listsquare will be updated accordingly:

```
>>> c.listsquare
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

But when I try:

```
>>> c.list[0] = 5
>>> c.list
[5, 2, 3, 4]
```

Listsquares is not updated:

```
>>> c.listsquare
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

How can I make listsquare auto update when I change only one item inside the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is by having a private helper `_List` class which is almost exactly like the built-in `list` class, but also has a `owner` attribute. Every time one of a `_List` instance's elements is assigned a value, it can then modify the `listsquare` property of its `owner` to keep it up-to-date. Since it's only used by `SomeClass` it can be nested inside of it to provide even more encapsulation.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    class _List(list):
        def __init__(self, owner, *args, **kwargs):
            super(SomeClass._List, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.owner = owner

        def __setitem__(self, index, value):
            super(SomeClass._List, self).__setitem__(index, value)
            self.owner.listsquare[index] = int(value**2)

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list = SomeClass._List(self, range(0, n))

    @property
    def list(self):
        return self._list
    @list.setter
    def list(self, val):
        self._list = val
        self._listsquare = [x**2 for x in self._list ]

    @property
    def listsquare(self):
        return self._listsquare
    @listsquare.setter
    def listsquare(self, val):
        self.list = [int(pow(x, 0.5)) for x in val]

c = SomeClass(5)
print(c.list)        # --> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(c.listsquare)  # --> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
c.list[0] = 5
print(c.list)        # --> [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(c.listsquare)  # --> [25, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend u not to change two, different attributes by accesing single list.setter. The reason why does:

```
>>> c.list[0] = 5
>>> c.list
[5, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c.listsquare
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

not work, is that, you are accesing the c.list.__setitem__ method.

```
c.list[0] = 5 
is equal to
c.list.__setitem__(0, 5)
or
list.__setitem__(c.list, 0, 5)
and as such, the list.__setitem__ method isn't the one you've implemented in your class.
```

However, if you really want to do so, you should reconsider creating the square list based on self._list.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list = range(0, n)

    @property
    def list(self):
        return self._list

    @list.setter
    def list(self, val):
        self._list = val

    @property
    def listsquare(self):
        return [n ** 2 for n in self.list]

    @listsquare.setter
    def listsquare(self, val):
        self.list = [int(pow(x, 0.5)) for x in val]
```