# How to auto update keys from a class inherited from dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I have a class that inherits from the `dict` class. In the example below, I define two keys 'x' and 'x2' with default value

```
class myClass(dict):
   def __init__(self,*arg,**kw):
      super(myClass, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)
      self['x']=2
      self['x2']=self['x']*self['x']
```

I want that they are linked in a way so that if I modify `'x'`, `'x2'` is updated by `x*x`, and if I modify `'x2'`, then `'x'` is updated to `sqrt(x)`

I found a post that explains a solution to do that for class attributes: [In class object, how to auto update attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916284/in-class-object-how-to-auto-update-attributes)

However, I cannot find a way to twist this example to make it work for dictionary keys. Does anyone has a clue about how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have only two keys is their a particular reason why you use a dictionary ?

Comment: You might want to try [overriding `dict.__setitem__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060972/subclassing-python-dictionary-to-override-setitem), and doing things in that method.

Comment: @scharette: the class I intend to create will be more complicated than the example I provided here for the sake of simplicity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sublassing dictionary is recommended sublass from `collections.UserDict`, not `dict`. With UsedDict, all your content is stored in `data` variable. [Manual pages here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict).

For desired functionality, you can redefine `__setitem__` special method:

```
import math
from collections import UserDict

class myClass(UserDict):
    def __init__(self,*arg,**kw):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)

        self.data['x'] = 2
        self.data['x2']= self['x'] * self['x']

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if key == 'x':
            self.data['x2'] = value * value
        elif key == 'x2':
            self.data['x2'] = math.sqrt(value)

c = myClass()
print(c['x'])
print(c['x2'])
print('-' * 80)
c['x'] = 4
print(c['x'])
print(c['x2'])
print('-' * 80)
c['x2'] = 9
print(c['x'])
print(c['x2'])
```

Output:

```
2
4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4
16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4
3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
However, I could not really understand the difference between `UserDict ` and `Dict`, even with the Manual page link you provide. Wouldn't it be possible to do it with a normal `Dict`?