# Using getter and setter with three attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, getter-setter

Please, explain what I do not understand about getters and setters, that this code catch the  exception already when I'm trying to instance the Test class?
The same, as it seems to me, have worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916491).

My goal is to update `c` depending on `a` and `b`, where all these properties should be accessible from outside of the class, i.e. public fields, as far as I understand.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, p1=50, p2=20):
        self.a = p1
        self.b = p2
    
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, val):
        self._a = val
        self._c = self.b - val // 5
    
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, val):
        self._b = val
    
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c
```

```py
>>> c = Test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\getter_and_setter.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.a = p1
  File "...\getter_and_setter.py", line 12, in a
    self._c = self.b - val // 5
  File "...\getter_and_setter.py", line 16, in b
    return self._b
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '_b'
```

Comment: Notice that sometimes your variables have an underscore, sometimes not. Shouldn't this be coherent all over the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is flaw in your implementation.

Setting `a` depends on `b` being already set. If you swap the 2 assignment statements in the `__init__` it will solve your current problem. However note there is big flaw in your implementation. If you change `b` that change will not be reflected in `c`.

There is no need to use getters and setters for `a` and `b`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, p1=50, p2=20):
        self.a = p1
        self.b = p2
    
    
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.b - self.a // 5
```