# How do you update variable in Class each time?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to code a Class, which upon calling, for example: `print(TimeNow.time_now)` would print current time (but it's not realtime), as in, each time I call it, it doesn't return updated value.

If I tried this every time, it would make my code long, so I am trying to code it in a Class so that I can easily call it wherever I want to print time:

```
time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(time_now)
```

Full code:

```
import datetime

command = ""

class TimeNow:
     time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

while command != "quit":
    command = input("-> ").lower()

    if command == "1":
    
         print(TimeNow.time_now)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In class object, how to auto update attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916284/in-class-object-how-to-auto-update-attributes)

Comment: Use a `property`!

Comment: Can you give me example? @KlausD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good case for a class definition.  A simple function will work:

```
def time_now():
     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(time_now())
```

Answer (score 1):

This method should work for what you want, but requires making an instance of TimeNow

```
import datetime

command = ""

class TimeNow:
    @property
    def time_now(self): 
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

instance = TimeNow()
    
while command != "quit":
    command = input("-> ").lower()
    if command == "1":
    
         print(instance.time_now)
```

Comment: I get this in output: <bound method TimeNow.time_now of <__main__.TimeNow object at 0x000002C8C16060A0>>